# Send imageURL to Firebase Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, web-applications, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I have a web app where said user would post text and an image which would be sent the Firebase DB. From there, it can be viewed online or on a mobile app I'm building with the Firebase backend. What I'm trying to accomplish is to use the URL from the image that is uploaded on my web app and send that to the DB so it can be also viewed on the mobile app. However, I haven't been able to get that to work.

My `Main.js`: https://pastebin.com/K2r93MeC

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a look at Zero to App (video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAsvwy1-oxE, source: https://gist.github.com/puf/8f67d3376d80ed2d02670d20bfc4ec7d) which shows how to do this.

Otherwise, post an error so we can take a look.